# How to adjust position of a node relative to others in beamer?

Tags: beamer

I want to adjust the two boxes labelled '1' to be in the same horizontal line, right from the first slide (just as it is in the last one)

```
\documentclass{beamer} 
\mode<presentation>{\usetheme{Madrid}}

\usepackage{tikz} 
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,positioning,decorations.pathmorphing} 
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, arrows} 
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,backgrounds,fit,matrix} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\tikzstyle{process} = [rectangle, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, text width=3cm, thick,draw=blue!50, fill=blue!10] 
\tikzstyle{box} = [minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, rounded corners,rectangle, fill=blue!50] 
\tikzstyle{arrow}= [thick,->,>=stealth]

\begin{document} %For boxes in background 
\pgfdeclarelayer{background layer} 
\pgfsetlayers{background layer,main}

\begin{frame}[t]%{Cloud}{} 
\begin{tikzpicture}[ every edge/.style = {draw, thick, -Stealth}] %
\path (-1,-1)rectangle(1,1); 
\node (box11) [box] {1};


\tikzstyle{box} = [minimum width=3cm, minimum height=2.5cm, rounded corners,rectangle, fill=blue!30] 
\node<+(1)-> (box12) [box, right of=box11,xshift=6cm] {1};

\tikzstyle{box} = [minimum width=1cm, minimum height=1cm, rounded corners,rectangle, fill=blue!50] 
\draw<.(1)-> [arrow] (box11.east) -- (box12.west);

\begin{pgfonlayer}{background layer} 
\node<.(1)-> [cloud, draw, align=left, cloud puffs=20,cloud puff arc=110, aspect=2, inner sep=0mm,fit= (box12) (box12)]{3}; 
\end{pgfonlayer}

\node<+(1)-> (box13) [box, right of=box12,yshift=-0.7cm] {2}; 
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the bounding box of the 3 slides are not identical. To find a sufficiently large box, just draw a rectangle that encompasses the 3.

```
\path[use as bounding box] (-1.5,2.2)rectangle(10.7,-2.2); 
%\draw (-1.5,2.2)rectangle(10.7,-2.2);  %<- bounding box
```

---

```
\documentclass{beamer} 
\mode<presentation>{\usetheme{Madrid}}

\usepackage{tikz} 
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,positioning,decorations.pathmorphing} \usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, arrows} \usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,backgrounds,fit,matrix} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\tikzstyle{process} = [rectangle, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, text width=3cm, thick,draw=blue!50, fill=blue!10] 
\tikzstyle{box} = [minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, rounded corners,rectangle, fill=blue!50] 
\tikzstyle{arrow}= [thick,->,>=stealth]

\begin{document} %For boxes in background 
\pgfdeclarelayer{background layer} 
\pgfsetlayers{background layer,main}

\begin{frame}[t]%{Cloud}{} 
\begin{tikzpicture}[ every edge/.style = {draw, thick, -Stealth}] %
\path[use as bounding box] (-1.5,2.2)rectangle(10.7,-2.2); 
%\path (-1.5,2.2)rectangle(10.7,-2.2); 
\node (box11) [box] {1};


\tikzstyle{box} = [minimum width=3cm, minimum height=2.5cm, rounded corners,rectangle, fill=blue!30] 
\node<+(1)-> (box12) [box, right of=box11,xshift=6cm] {1};

\tikzstyle{box} = [minimum width=1cm, minimum height=1cm, rounded corners,rectangle, fill=blue!50] 
\draw<.(1)-> [arrow] (box11.east) -- (box12.west);

\begin{pgfonlayer}{background layer} 
\node<.(1)-> [cloud, draw, align=left, cloud puffs=20,cloud puff arc=110, aspect=2, inner sep=0mm,fit= (box12) (box12)]{3}; 
\end{pgfonlayer}

\node<+(1)-> (box13) [box, right of=box12,yshift=-0.7cm] {2}; \end{tikzpicture}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Fantastic, thanks for not only correcting it but also giving intuition to it.